# Generating a list in prolog

Tags: prolog

Hello I want to make a program in Prolog, that given a list of numbers and a number, it appends all the concurences of position of the number in a second list.

For example for the `list (5,10,4,5,6,5)` and `number =5` the new list should be

```
(1,4,6)
```

here is my code so far

```
positions(X, [X|_],1).
positions(X, [P|T], N) :- positions(X, T, N1), N is N1+1.

find(X, [H|T] ,Z) :-positions(X,[H|T],N) , append([],N,Z).
```

the positions returns the first concurrence of X in the list, but I don't know how to proceed. Can you help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it's not an assignment, then you can benefit from using the built-ins findall/3 and nth1/3:

```
?- findall(Nth, nth1(Nth, [5,10,4,5,6,5], 5), Nths).
Nths = [1, 4, 6].
```

Taking just the nth1 phrase, and running that, you can see it is backtracking and finding multiple solutions, then we just use findall to collect them into a list.

```
?- nth1(Nth, [5,10,4,5,6,5], 5).
Nth = 1 ;
Nth = 4 ;
Nth = 6.
```

nth1/3, when using a variable for the first parameter, is saying 'give me a list index where where the 3rd parameter is found in the list of the second parameter.

Answer (score 2):

You have some good ideas, but I would suggest a couple things:

1) In Prolog, it can be beneficial to give variables meaningful names

2) Use an accumulator and you will only need positions and append

3)Use a different base case

```
positions([Num|List],Num,[Index|SubResult],Index) :- Index2 is Index+1, 
                                        positions(List,Num,SubResult,Index2).

positions([NotNum|List],Num,Result,Index) :- NotNum \= Num,
                                          Index2 is Index+1, 
                                          positions(List,Num,Result,Index2).

positions([],Num,[],Index).
```

In our first general case, we can see the numbers match, so we go find how many results are in our sublist, which we will call the `SubResult` and then push the current index on to our `SubResult`

The next general case, the numbers do not unify, and our `Result` IS the `SubResult`, so let's call them the same thing.

In our final case (the base case) we can see the list is empty, in this case we return an empty list as we cannot match against an empty list.

You can see that the above rules are *order-independent*, which is something very valuable in Prolog. This means you can arrange the rules in any order, and the semantics of your Prolog program remain unchanged. Using unification to achieve this will prevent future pain in debugging.

We can wrap our predicate in the following way

```
positions(Num, List, Positions) :- positions(List, Num, Positions, 1).
```

This will allow for queries of `positions(5,[5,10,4,5,6,5],Positions).`

Comment: +1 because I like the solution, and randomly because you like the word "Pythonic". No Prolog equivalent term sounds as cool ("prologish"? "prological"?...)

Comment: @mbratch "prologgy"? I'd say "prological" is the best out of our set of adjectives. Prolog is pro-logic?

Comment: Agreed. Of those options, "Prological" rolls off the tongue the best I think.